# How to make a path from a string in starlark?

Tags: bazel, starlark

I'm writing some validation code for a bazel build rule and I need to do some path validation. I need to check that a certain file exists in the same directory as the BUILD file. I notice that there's a context attribute [`build_file_path`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/ctx.html#build_file_path) which points to the BUILD file. I'd like to extract the parent directory from this.

It looks like I can't create a new [`path`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/path.html) object - I don't see a constructor/initializer. It also seems like Starlark doesn't support `os.path` like python because imports aren't supported.

What's the canonical way to get the parent directory of a string object representing a path in Starlark?

Comment: Any chance you ever solved this? I'm trying to do a very similar thing. I need to create a symlink, but [unresolved symlinks are only in expermintal](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#symlink). I cannot find anywhere in the api that makes a path object available to you when executing a rule.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't and I don't remember if I ended up dropping the task that required this validation work (it's been so long...)

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your final question, but hopefully the following will help with the initial problem:

You could use the Label of the target for which this instance of the rule is being built and find its package. This will give you a string representing the parent directory of the BUILD file.

i.e. ctx.label.package

Comment: That helps but unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. Maybe I'm not being creative enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:paths.bzl", "paths")

paths.dirname(path_str)
```

See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/docs/paths_doc.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).